# Generate a sequence of characters from 'A'-'Z'

Tags: r, character, ascii, sequence, seq

I can make a sequence of numbers like this:

```
s = seq(from=1, to=10, by=1)
```

How do I make a sequence of characters from A-Z? This doesn't work:

```
seq(from=1, to=10)
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use `LETTERS` and `letters` (for uppercase and lowercase respectively).

Answer (score 48):

Use the code you have with `letters` and/or `LETTERS`:

```
> LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
> letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

Comment: Or just  LETTERS[1:10]

Answer (score 16):

Just use the predefined variables `letters` and `LETTERS`.

And for completeness, here it something using `seq`:

```
R> rawToChar(as.raw(seq(as.numeric(charToRaw('a')), as.numeric(charToRaw('z')))))
[1] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
R>
```

Answer (score 12):

*R.oo* package has an `intToChar` function, that uses ASCII values, if `LETTERS` and `letters` aren't any good. A is 65 in ASCII:

```
> require(R.oo)
> intToChar(65:79)
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O"
```

or you can use the fact that the lowest unicode numbers are ascii and hence `intToUtf8` in R-base like this:

```
> intToUtf8(65:78,multiple=TRUE)
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N"
```

or faff around with `rawToChar`:

```
> rawToChar(as.raw(65:78))
[1] "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN"
```

Answer (score 2):

`LETTERS` returns A-Z

To generate A-E for instance

Uppercase:

```
> LETTERS[1:5]
```

Lowercase

```
letters[1:5]
```