# Generating a (random) sequence of multiple characters in R

Tags: r, random

1. I can create a sequence of single letters using

   ```
   LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]
   letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]
   ```
2. I can create a random string of various length, using the `random` package

   ```
   library(random)
   string <- randomStrings(n=10, len=5, digits=TRUE, upperalpha=TRUE,
                     loweralpha=TRUE, unique=TRUE, check=TRUE)
   ```

Unfortunately, I cannot use the `set.seed` function for example `2`.

Is there a way to create the same (random) combination of (unique) strings everytime one runs a R-file?

My result would look like this (with the same result everytime I run the function):

```
       V1     
  [1,] "k7QET"
  [2,] "CLlWm"
  [3,] "yPuwh"
  [4,] "JJqEX"
  [5,] "38soF"
  [6,] "xkozk"
  [7,] "uaiOW"
  [8,] "tZcrW"
  [9,] "8K4Cc"
 [10,] "RAhuU"
```

Comment: @Richard Scriven I am looking for something like `set.seed(5)
v1 <- runif(10, 0, 1)`. I always have the same numbers in the vector v1, but they are still random numbers

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood your question correctly. You want to have a vector of a series of random characters (strings) but you want them to be exactly the same every time you run the script? doesn't this somehow defeats the whole purpose of random generation? Anyway I guess you could store them just in a file and just load them every time. BTW upvoted because you helped m find the right answer to random string generation :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a file, say test.R, add the following

```
set.seed(1)
stringi::stri_rand_strings(10, 5)
```

Then it's reproducible every time.

```
replicate(5, source("test.R", verbose = FALSE)$value)
#       [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    
#  [1,] "GNZuC" "GNZuC" "GNZuC" "GNZuC" "GNZuC" 
#  [2,] "twed3" "twed3" "twed3" "twed3" "twed3"
#  [3,] "CAgNl" "CAgNl" "CAgNl" "CAgNl" "CAgNl"
#  [4,] "UizNm" "UizNm" "UizNm" "UizNm" "UizNm" 
#  [5,] "vDe7G" "vDe7G" "vDe7G" "vDe7G" "vDe7G"
#  [6,] "N0NrL" "N0NrL" "N0NrL" "N0NrL" "N0NrL"
#  [7,] "TbUBp" "TbUBp" "TbUBp" "TbUBp" "TbUBp"
#  [8,] "fn6iP" "fn6iP" "fn6iP" "fn6iP" "fn6iP" 
#  [9,] "oemYW" "oemYW" "oemYW" "oemYW" "oemYW"
# [10,] "m1Tjg" "m1Tjg" "m1Tjg" "m1Tjg" "m1Tjg"
```

As an alternative to `source()`, you could use `parse()` there.

```
replicate(5, eval(parse("test.R")))
```

Comment: exactly. thx. for my purpose, it would be sufficient to use `set.seed(1)
stringi::stri_rand_strings(100, 5)` only

Answer (score 9):

An alternate solution in base R:

```
set.seed(1)
result <- rawToChar(as.raw(sample(c(65:90,97:122), 5, replace=T)))
```

*Inspired by this answer to another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4370074/8297546*

Answer (score 0):

Make some random number vector (in a range) and give them to `intToUtf8`.

This solution could generates random characters, and you don't need to import any libraries. *(well I just need a `magrittr` to pretty my code ...)*

---

e.g.

You can use this to see a code number in UTF-8 means which character:

```r
#' @license mit
#' 

#' @examples 
#' 
#' `9999 %>% seq %>% utf8_see`
#' `19894:19999 %>% utf8_see`
#' ...
#' 
#' `c(65:90,97:122) %>% utf8_see` is A-Z and a-z
#' `48:57 %>% utf8_see` is 0-9
#' `9200:9203 %>% utf8_see` is some clock emoji
#' `10240:10495 %>% utf8_see` is the brailles
#' `c(768:879,1155:1158,1160:1161) %>% utf8_see` is some zero width char
#' `c(688:705,710:740,748:767,1159) %>% utf8_see` is some super/sub scripts
#' `c(94,581,652,654,710,923,955) %>% utf8_see` is some lambda like char
#' ...
#' 
utf8_see = function (n) `names<-`(n,n) |> 
    vapply (intToUtf8, FUN.VALUE="character") ;
```

You can just execute the codes in the examples by yourself.

Then, you can just use `sample(n)` to pick some number in it, and trans them into character with `intToUtf8`. Such as:

```r
c(65:90,97:122) %>% sample(5) %>% intToUtf8
```

This will give you a `5` length string with random letters, or you can make this many time i.e.

```r
7 %>% seq %>% vapply(\ (x) c(65:90,97:122) %>% sample(5) %>% intToUtf8, FUN.VALUE="character")
```

So we can also make a tool:

```r
library(magrittr)

#' @license agpl-3.0
#' @author y.ypa.yhm
#' 
rand.chars = \ (char.set) \ (len, times) times %>% seq %>% 
    vapply(\ (x) char.set %>% sample(len) %>% intToUtf8, FUN.VALUE="character")

`%a2z.randchars%` = c(65:90,97:122) %>% rand.chars
`%braille.randchars%` = 10240:10495 %>% rand.chars
`%num.randchars%` = 48:57 %>% rand.chars
`%lambda.randchars%` = c(94,581,652,654,710,923,955) %>% rand.chars
```

Then use like:

- `5 %a2z.randchars% 10`
- `3 %braille.randchars% 4`
- `9 %num.randchars% 3`
- `4 %lambda.randchars% 3`

This is my generations:

```
> 5 %a2z.randchars% 10
 [1] "OzQIv" "wQume" "SWaQL" "nBmSE" "gjSvR" "lTMfe" "kJGqt"
 [8] "FcGnf" "jsEUw" "AhFRf"
> 3 %braille.randchars% 4
[1] "⢿⠖⡵" "⣒⠥⣑" "⣮⠨⡆" "⠘⠗⡇"
> 9 %num.randchars% 3
[1] "139475082" "286974310" "389520461"
> 4 %lambda.randchars% 3
[1] "ˆʌɅ^"  "Ʌ^λˆ" "ʎ^λɅ"
```

All codes tested at the *[Webr Playground](https://webr.r-wasm.org/latest/)* and *R Studio*, here is a demo on *[Shinylive](https://shinylive.io/r/editor/#code=NobwRAdghgtgpmAXGAxgCygJwM4DpNgA0qA9hAC5wVJgDEA5AAQACANgJYpXZyMzvkAOhAaNhw0czgAPWAAdWcbGJFMJTAAYBOHVsYBSAHz7GPAI4HjjAK7kAZgA4A+jzgb1jDQEYtDrQBZEH11LE1tHFzg3D1xYjw8NFAAKADYAVkQtAAZCLQB2IIAmQoBKUJt7Z1cNRnZlAEEAWgAtRigIABM2xoAvBP8HRDS88vCqqJq6xizGrQStQqyszMWAZlHKyLda5WwSeEYUVhIUAGtGOBgSACt2BK8swv9lh-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-kmKsfWaP4BhJSlXUNeNCEbmAAC+AC6QA)*.

Enjoy it.