# Create a sequence between two letters

Tags: r, character

I want to create a sequence between two letters let's say `"b"` and `"f"`. So the output is

```
"b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
```

For numbers, we can do

```
2:6 #which gives output as 
[1] 2 3 4 5 6
```

Is there an easy way to do this with letters as well?

I have gone through [Generate a sequence of characters from 'A'-'Z'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370033/generate-a-sequence-of-characters-from-a-z)
 but this produces all the letters and not sequence between specific letters.

My current solution is,

```
indx <- which(letters %in% c("b", "f")); 
letters[indx[1] : indx[2]]

#[1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
```

This works but I am curious if there is an easy way to do this or a function in any of the package that I have missed?

**Note:** I do not want `letters[2:6]` as I do not know 2 and 6 beforehand. It could be between any two letters.

Comment: What defines your set of "letters"? Do you want the 26 lower-case letters of the Latin alphabet, or do you  want the set of letters in the users current locale? Which could be the french, greek, russian, arabic or other alphabet?

Comment: @Spacedman yes, currently looking only for 26 letters from Latin alphabet.

Comment: "I do not want letters[2:6] as I do not know 2 and 6 beforehand." So I take it the reason you don't want to do `letters[begin:end]` is that you want to generate it based on the limits being given as letters rather than numbers?

Comment: @Acccumulation correct. I have input as letters and not numbers.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This would be another base R option:

```
letters[(letters >= "b") & (letters <= "f")]
# [1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
```

Answer (score 28):

You can create your own function:

```
`%:%` <- function(l, r) {
    intToUtf8(seq(utf8ToInt(l), utf8ToInt(r)), multiple = TRUE)
}
```

Usage:

```
"b" %:% "f"
# [1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"

"f" %:% "b"
# [1] "f" "e" "d" "c" "b"

"A" %:% "D"
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

Comment: Ow, nice, didn't know about `"multiple = TRUE"` option.

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, this parameter makes `intToUtf8` a very handy function.

Comment: Definitely better than my use of `raw`.

Answer (score 17):

Another option with `match`, `seq` and `do.call`:

```
letters[do.call(seq, as.list(match(c("b","f"), letters)))]
```

which gives:

> ```
> [1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
> ```

---

Making a function of this such that it works with both lower-case and upper-case letters:

```
char_seq <- function(lets) {
  switch(all(grepl("[[:upper:]]", lets)) + 1L,
         letters[do.call(seq, as.list(match(lets, letters)))],
         LETTERS[do.call(seq, as.list(match(lets, LETTERS)))])
}
```

the output of this:

> ```
> > char_seq(c("b","f"))
> [1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
>
> > char_seq(c("B","F"))
> [1] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
> ```

This function can be extended with checks on the correctness of the input:

```
char_seq <- function(lets) {
  g <- grepl("[[:upper:]]", lets)
  if(length(g) != 2) stop("Input is not of length 2")
  if(sum(g) == 1) stop("Input does not have all lower-case or all upper-case letters")
  switch(all(g) + 1L,
         letters[do.call(seq, as.list(match(lets, letters)))],
         LETTERS[do.call(seq, as.list(match(lets, LETTERS)))])
}
```

resulting in proper error-messages when the input is not correct:

> ```
> > char_seq(c("B"))
> Error in char_seq(c("B")) : Input is not of length 2
>
> > char_seq(c("b","F"))
> Error in char_seq(c("b", "F")) : 
>   Input does not have all lower-case or all upper-case letters
> ```

Answer (score 15):

Playing with UTF, something like:

```
intToUtf8(utf8ToInt("b"):utf8ToInt("f"), multiple = TRUE)
# [1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
```

Answer (score 13):

Why not?

```
letters[which(letters == 'b') : which(letters == 'f')]
```

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps using the raw versions of letters and then converting back to character could be used to define an infix function analogous to `":"`

```
 `%c:%` <- function(x,y) { strsplit( rawToChar(as.raw(
     seq(as.numeric(charToRaw(x)), as.numeric(charToRaw(y))))), "" )[[1]]}
>  'a' %c:% 'g'
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"
```

I'm certainly not claiming this satisfies the request for "an easy way to do this" and I'm not even certain it would be more efficient, but it does introduce a couple of potentially useful functions.

Comment: "it does introduce a couple of potentially useful functions" Can you develop?

Comment: I often find the process of locating conversion functions like `charToRaw` and `rawToChar` difficult. Also in the list of functions I have trouble remembering are: `intToUtf8` and `chartr`, `sfsmisc::AsciiToInt`, `stringi::stri_enc_isascii`, `stringi::stri_enc_toascii`. The last few I located by using `??ascii`. I think there are a few other utility functions that I sometimes can locate, but not at this moment cannot. I had a lsit in my `.Rprofile` file on my "regular" computer but I'm now converting from Mac to Linux and don't have it running.

Comment: I see your point, having myself difficulties to remember functions that I've used months ago. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Iknow it is frowned upon, but here is an `eval(parse(...))` solution

```
LETTERS[eval(parse(text = paste(which(LETTERS %in% c('B', 'F')), collapse = ':')))]
#[1] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```

Comment: Using `eval` and `parse` here is blatant abuse, sorry. You can implement the same logic without (e.g. with `do.call`), although the logic itself is also needlessly convoluted.

Answer (score 4):

First things first: your code

```
which(letters %in% c("b", "f"))
```

Is a valid but convoluted way of writing

```
match(c('b', 'f'), letters)
```

(Why “convoluted”? Because `%in%` is a wrapper around `match` for a specific use-case, which explicitly turns the numeric index into a logical value, i.e. the inverse operation of `which`.)

Next, you can of course use the result and convert it into a range via `idx[1L] : idx[2L]` and there’s nothing wrong with that in this case. But R has an idiomatic way of expressing the concept of calling a function using a vector as its parameters: [`do.call`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/do.call):

```
do.call(`:`, as.list(match(c('b', 'f'), letters)))
```

Or, equivalently:

```
do.call(seq, as.list(match(c('b', 'f'), letters)))
```

{purrr} allows us to do the same without the `as.list`:

```
purrr::invoke(seq, match(c('b', 'f'), letters))
```

And, finally, we subset:

```
letters[purrr::invoke(seq, match(c('b', 'f'), letters))]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `grep` and `letters` and the pattern `[b-f]`.

```
grep("[b-f]", letters, value = TRUE)
#[1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"

letters[grep("[b-f]", letters)]
#[1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"

letters[grepl("[b-f]", letters)]
#[1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
```

And for a decreasing sequence you can use in addition `rev`

```
rev(grep("[b-f]", letters, value = TRUE))
#[1] "f" "e" "d" "c" "b"
```

or using `match`.

```
letters[match("b", letters) : match("f", letters)]
#[1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
```

Answer (score 1):

A compact solution using `match`

```r
library(magrittr)

a <- "b"
b <- "f"

letters %>% .[match(a,.):match(b,.)]
#> [1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>