# method for expand a-z to abc...xyz form R

Tags: r

Hi:) what i'm trying to do is write a simple program to expand from shortest entry

for example

a-z

to longest write

for example

abcdefghijklmnouprstwxyz

Any ideas on how to implement that in R? Thanks

Comment: I think this should give you some ideas. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476833/create-a-sequence-between-two-letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do

```
paste(letters[do.call(`:`, as.list(match( strsplit(str1, "-")[[1]], 
       letters)))], collapse="")
[1] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

---

The above could be wrapped in a function

```
f1 <- function(string1) {
     paste(letters[do.call(`:`, as.list(match( strsplit(string1, "-")[[1]], 
       letters)))], collapse="")
}
```

Using the new data

```
i1 <- grep('-', df$letters)
df$letters[i1] <- sapply(df$letters[i1], f1)

df$letters
[1] "abc"  "bcd"  "cd"   "abcd" "ab"   "cd"
```

---

Or use `regex`

```
paste(grep(sprintf('[%s]', str1), letters, value = TRUE), collapse="")
```

---

Based on the new dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   separate(letters, into = c('start', 'end'), 
         sep="(?<=[a-z])-?(?=[a-z])") %>% 
   transmute(new = map2_chr(match(start, letters),
       match(end, letters), ~ str_c(letters[.x:.y], collapse="")))
```

-output

```
  new
1  abc
2  bcd
3   cd
4 abcd
5   ab
6   cd
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "a-z"
df<-data.frame(letters=c("a-c","b-d","c-d","a-d", "ab", "cd"))
```

Comment: How would you approach the same issue in a dataset like below?                                       
df<-data.frame(letters=c("a-c","b-d","c-d","a-d", "ab", "cd"))

Comment: @ViniciusGarnica where is the dataset you mentioned as below

Comment: @ViniciusGarnica in some of the elements there are no `-`? Is it a typo

Comment: @ViniciusGarnica already updated the answer.  I used tidyverse.  But, the other one should also work if we loop with lapply/sapply and apply the function f1.  I think based on the pattern you only need to loop where the `-` exists