# How can we use complete for alphabetic letters?

Tags: r, tidyr

**I have this dataframe:**

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(1, 5, 6, 7, 8), y = c("a", "e", "f", "g", 
"h")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

      x y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     5 e    
3     6 f    
4     7 g    
5     8 h
```

**With `complete` from  `tidyr` package:
I can do:**

```
df %>% 
  complete(x = full_seq(min(x):max(x), 1))

      x y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 NA   
3     3 NA   
4     4 NA   
5     5 e    
6     6 f    
7     7 g    
8     8 h
```

**Now I would like to do the same with the `y` column:**

```
df %>% 
  complete(y = full_seq(min(y):max(y), 1))
```

This obviously will not work.

**How can I use `complete` from `tidyr` package for alphabetical order?**

Comment: Related: [Create a sequence between two letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476833/create-a-sequence-between-two-letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, especially because except in the case of 1 letter, it would not be possible to complete strings with more than one letter. You can still use the `letters` data set:

```r
df %>% 
  complete(y = letters[full_seq(min(x):max(x), 1)])
```

or, to be entirely relying on `y`:

```r
df %>% 
  complete(y = letters[which(letters == min(y)):which(letters == max(y))])
```

```r
  y         x
1 a         1
2 b        NA
3 c        NA
4 d        NA
5 e         5
6 f         6
7 g         7
8 h         8
```